# Chain rule for the derivative of a composite function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$y=(\sin x)^{\sqrt{x}}.$$

I know that I suppose to apply the chain rule here, but I can't get clearly what
is the composition here.

Comment: Take logarithms first.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use logarithmic differentiation here:
\begin{align*}
y&=(\sin(x))^{\sqrt{x}} \\
\ln(y)&=\sqrt{x}\,\ln(\sin(x)) \\
\frac1y\,\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac12\,x^{-1/2}\,\ln(\sin(x))+\sqrt{x}\,\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}.
\end{align*}
Can you finish?

The problem with the straight-forward approach is that you don't have a power rule, nor do you have an exponent rule you can use. It's a bit analogous to differentiating $x^x$.

Comment: Is adding ln to both sides of the equation is conventional? Is it like basic arithmetic actions(subtracting, adding etc...)?

Comment: You're taking the logarithm of both sides. I skipped one step going from the first line to the second: I used the logarithm property that $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$.

Comment: This is what I get: (dy/dx)=((y*ln(sinx))/(2*(x^0.5)))  +  (y*(x^0.5))/(tanx) . Is it safe to assume that this is the right anser?

Comment: Normally, if possible, you want to eliminate the $y$'s on the RHS. How could you do that?

Comment: How am I supposed to eliminate the Y ? I do the deriative of y with respect to x. then I nedd to isolate it(dy/dx) by dividing both sides of equation by 1/y.

Comment: How about using the original equation, before differentiating?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79201/discussion-between-user6394019-and-adrian-keister).

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you write $$y=e^{\sqrt{x}\ln(\sin(x))}$$ Then $$y'=e^{\sqrt{x}\ln(\sin(x))}(\sqrt{x}\ln(\sin(x)))'=(\sin(x))^{\sqrt{x}}(\sqrt{x}\ln(\sin(x)))'$$

Now you only have to differentiate $\sqrt{x}\ln(\sin(x))$, in which case you need the product rule and the chain rule.